# Unwanted margins in xaringan PDF created using pagedown

Tags: r, pagedown, xaringan

I've been creating html slides using `xaringan` and I want to save them as PDF. I'm trying to use `pagedown::chrome_print`, however the output is generated with unwanted margins that aren't displyed in the html version. Do you know how can I solve it?

This is my YAML header

```
title: "Example"
subtitle: "1"
author: "Edo"
institute: ""
date: ""
output: 
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: [mymetropolis.css, metropolis-fonts]
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      ratio: '16:9'
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Using the xaringan skeleton and `chrome_print` without any other argument, I get a well rendered pdf with no extra margins.

Comment: I've tried with the xaringan basic template and it works. I'm using a slightly modified version of the metropolis theme, do you think it could depend on that? I just added the YAML header to the question. Thank you

Comment: I would bet on the `mymetropolis.css` being the source of the margins. A bit unsure about the ratio parameter as well.

Comment: The ratio doesn't seem to make any difference. I'll try to look for something into the `mymetropolis.css`

Comment: Did you find the source of the margins?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't. In the end I used the html version

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `css: [default, mymetropolis.css, metropolis-fonts]`